# What happens if a posix mutex is unlocked while multiple threads are blocked on this mutex?

Tags: multithreading, posix

```
thread 1:
     lock mutex1
     long time operation
     unlock mutex1

thread2:
     lock mutex1
     ...

thread3:
     lock mutex1
     ...

thread4:
     lock mutex1
     ...

threadn:
     lock mutex1
     ...
```

When thread1 unlocks mutex1, which thread will be woken up? Is there a standard specification for it?

Comment: In which language? There is no universal response.

Comment: Do you expect an answer for POSIX mutexes, or for the mutexes defined natively in C++11, or for both?

Comment: @Étienne POSIX mutextes, Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when thread1 unlock mutex1, which thread will be woken up?

One of the other threads that are currently blocked on the mutex. It is unspecified which of them.

> Is there a standard specification for it?

No. Different systems may implement it in different ways. (Some might use a simple fifo order for waking the threads, others might use heuristics for deciding which thread to wake up).

Answer (score 3):

When you unlock a posix mutex using `pthread_mutex_unlock`, if several threads are waiting on the mutex only one of them will wake up.

The [documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_mutex_unlock) states:

> If there are threads blocked on the mutex object referenced by mutex
>   when pthread_mutex_unlock() is called, resulting in the mutex becoming
>   available, the scheduling policy shall determine which thread shall
>   acquire the mutex.